# Does java cache a standard GET request?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

So I wrote a program where I am running an infinite number of GET requests to retrieve a json file from a remote server. The program is complete when the json file is changed. I am running two instances of the program. My problem is that one program detects the file change, while the other still doesn't detect the file change.

The json file is very simple,

> {"status":"complete"}

and

> {"status":"incomplete"}

The basic psuedo code is,

```
  while(status == "incomplete") {
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
      "http://www.website.com/file.json");
      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
      ...
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps the easiest solution to avoid caching is adding `?timestamp=128318238123` to the url ... And you might want to have a look here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html

Comment: so compare your two programs and see how they differ

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set caching on server side by setting following parameters:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); //
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache `HttpClient` 4.5 supports caching, but the default client is not caching, see [HTTP Caching](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/caching.html):

> HttpClient Cache provides an HTTP/1.1-compliant caching layer to be used with HttpClient--the Java equivalent of a browser cache. The implementation follows the Chain of Responsibility design pattern, where the caching HttpClient implementation can serve a drop-in replacement for the default non-caching HttpClient implementation; requests that can be satisfied entirely from the cache will not result in actual origin requests. Stale cache entries are automatically validated with the origin where possible, using conditional GETs and the If-Modified-Since and/or If-None-Match request headers.